# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.hide()'

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

This error seems to be happening only on Samsung phones. I looked on the Internet and I didn't find a practical solution

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.hide()' on a null object reference
   at android.widget.Editor.stopTextActionMode(Editor.java:2687)
   at android.widget.Editor.prepareCursorControllers(Editor.java:822)
   at android.widget.TextView.nullLayouts(TextView.java:9157)
   at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:10105)
   at android.widget.TextView.setHintInternal(TextView.java:6538)
   at android.widget.TextView.setHint(TextView.java:6527)
   at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(TextInputLayout.java:5)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(ViewGroup.java:3774)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(ViewGroup.java:3774)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(ViewGroup.java:3774)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(ViewGroup.java:3774)
   at android.app.assist.AssistStructure$WindowNode.<init>(AssistStructure.java:517)
   at android.app.assist.AssistStructure.<init>(AssistStructure.java:2047)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRequestAssistContextExtras(ActivityThread.java:3387)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1906)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7073)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:974)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: have you found a solution? facing the same issue

Comment: I applied the easiest solution,
if (Build.MODEL.contains("SM-J8")){
            editText.getEditText().setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

Comment: I get this bug only from Samsung J8

Comment: Is there any solution of this question?